# Consuming ASP .NET Web service with Java Script JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, web-services

I'm trying to consume Web service developed in ASP .net with html and Java Script/AJAX. But it is not working .

Here is Web Service Method:

```
[ScriptService]
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
[WebMethod]
//[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string HelloWorld()
{
    String msg = "Hello User";
    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(msg);

}
```

Here is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function Logon() 
{
 $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:49804/Service1.asmx/HelloWorld",
            data: "{}", //ur data to be sent to server
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
               alert(data);
            },
            error: function (x, y, z) {
               alert(x.responseText +"  " +x.status);
            }
        });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" onSubmit="Logon()" autocomplete="on">
  username:<input type="text" id="fname"><br>
  password: <input type="text" id="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Web service method in browser:
[image]

Please ignore username and password fields, I want to use it later.
Is it a problem of Web service? I see SOAP request and response listed in browser page? or its a js problem ?

Thanks

Comment: why have you got it in the head and have you stepped through it does your console log give you any errors in your browser??